# Quartz CronTrigger migration to 2.2.x

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm in the process of upgrading Quartz from 1.8.6 to 2.2.x and I have a question about creating Cron Triggers and setting expressions.

In the old code it was handled like this:

```
String expression = cronSchedule.getExpression();
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();

try {
    trigger.setCronExpression(expression);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("unparsable cron expression", e);
  }
```

Migrating to the new APIs, I'm wondering if this will accomplish the same thing:

```
String expression = cronSchedule.getExpression();
Trigger trigger;

try {
  trigger = newTrigger()
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule(expression))
    .build();
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("unparsable cron expression", e);
  }
```

In the second example, I wouldn't need the try/catch, I think, but I'm not even sure if this is the the correct way to set a cron expression since I can't find much documentation in the JavaDocs.

Comment: Does your example work? If not, how did it fail?

Comment: It certainly compiles, but I won't have a chance to test it until I fix everything else that's broken in the code. I was just curious if that would be the right way to go about it.